# How to use fragments backstack with shared element transition

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-animation, shared-element-transition

Shared element transition replace the fragment, so I can't add it to the backstack and call popbackstack when the back arrow button is pressed.

I have a main activity with inside a mainfragment. The main fragment handles a table layout, so each tab is a fragment with inside a recycler view. When a recycler view element is clicked, the shared element transition starts to a new fragment that shows element details.

This is the adapter, where the element is clicked:

```
holder.image.setTransitionName("transition" + holder.getAdapterPosition());
if (fragment instanceof tab1_anime) {
     ((tab1_anime) fragment).openShowElementFragment(holder.getAdapterPosition(), v.findViewById(R.id.main_image));
}
```

This is the openShowElementFragment inside my tab fragment:

```
public void openShowElementFragment(int position, View view) {
    AddElement element = anime_list.get(position);
    ShowElementFragment showElementFragment = new ShowElementFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("transitionName", "transition" + position);
    bundle.putSerializable("element", element);
    bundle.putInt("position", position);
    bundle.putInt("from", 0);
    showElementFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    ((MainActivity) context).showFragmentWithTransition(this, showElementFragment, "showElementFragment", view, "transition" + position);
}
```

This is the openshowelementfragment function called in the previous code block:

```
public void showFragmentWithTransition(Fragment current, Fragment newFragment, String tag, View sharedView, String sharedElementName) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    // Check if the fragment is in back stack
    boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag, 0);
    if (fragmentPopped) {

    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            current.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
            current.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));

            newFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
            newFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, newFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .addSharedElement(sharedView, sharedElementName)
            .commit();
    }
}
```

And this is the backarrow button:

```
back_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
});
```

If I try to add the new fragment instead of replacing the old one, then there aren't any animations at all.

If I try to replace the old fragment with the new one and using the addtobackstack(null) anyway, then the shared element transition works from start to end *but* the fragment at the end is without data, empty:

[image]

I also tried:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, new MainFragment())
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

But in this way, the shared element transition doesn't work on exit:

[image]

Comment: Did you read the [documentation specifically about return shared element transitions when using RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#recyclerview)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes, but if I got it in the right way, that case is from a fragment to a recycler view, and it's not my case

Comment: That's exactly what your return transition is.

Answer (score 0):

Your so-called `sharedElementName` is actually a `transitionName`.

a) The reference example doesn't directly manipulate the backstack:
[Android Fragment Transitions: RecyclerView to ViewPager](https://github.com/android/animation-samples/tree/master/GridToPager) and [Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html).

b) Manual transactions might require another order of method calls:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .addSharedElement(sharedElement, transitionName)
    .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

Also see [this example](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb), how alternate transitions could be be set, compared to:

```
TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition)
```

Whatever `R.transition.default_transition` may be.

It may look strange when using the same transition for both ways, instead of enter/exit transitions, alike `NavAction` would feature. [`FragmentNavigator.Extras`](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions#set-fragment) could be used to apply enter/exit transitions, when using navigation component; this also can be combined with `ActionBar`. Option a) is probably less complicated. b) something alike [this](https://www.kodeco.com/8279305-navigation-component-for-android-part-3-transition-and-navigation) Kotlin example might make more sense.

It's pointless to build clunky navigation FX when enter/exit transitions would be [supported out-of-the-box](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions). Maybe consider loading with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), when loading images.

---

Assume the following `build.gradle`; there isn't any need to reinvent the wheel.

```
dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:2.5.3"
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
}
```

Then `Navigation` with `FragmentNavigator.Extras` might rather be the current method:

```
Bundle navArgs = new Bundle();
navArgs.putInt("position", position);

FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
    .addSharedElement(sharedElement, transitionName)
    .build();

Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(
    R.id.details, // ID of Nav destination
    navArgs,      // Bundle of args
    null,         // NavOptions
    extras);
```

One can also define transitionName in XML `<action/>` nodes.

Comment: What is *"FX"*? *[Fragment transition](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html)*)? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the exit transition as you get a solution of an empty list. Now for an exit transition effect, check the below code.

```
 public void showFragmentWithTransition(Fragment current, Fragment newFragment, String tag, View sharedView, String sharedElementName) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Check if the fragment is in back stack
    boolean fragmentPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(tag, 0);
    if (fragmentPopped) {

    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            current.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
            current.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));

            newFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
            newFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
            newFragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
            newFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
        }
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .addSharedElement(sharedElement, transitionName)
             .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
    }
}
```

Here I add two new lines for exit transitions.

> ```
> newFragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
> newFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.default_transition));
> ```

If it does not work then follow *[Fragment transitions with shared elements](https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb)*. I think it will help you.

Comment: Using the same transition twice doesn't make sense... it's usually two transitions, while one can assign four different ones.